# how to USE CORS in Ionic Angular

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, cors, httpservice

i am trying to do a get request using ionic http service. But i have come to this cross origin error which i got:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1/webService/getBlogs.php. Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin
```

well i searched for solutions but due to my limited understanding i was lost and don't know what to do.
Some say go to ionic.project and change the proxy to a full url. 
Some say change some code in node js server and i don't know which file and where i can find that.

Can someone guide me on how to setup CORS and where to set a header information?

Here is my code below:

```
var TMSApp = angular.module("TMSApp",["ionic"]);

TMSApp.service("TMSSvc",["$http","$rootScope",TMSSvc]);

TMSApp.controller("TMSCtrl",["$scope","$sce","$ionicLoading","TMSSvc",TMSCtrl]);

function TMSCtrl($scope, $sce,$ionicLoading,TMSSvc){

    $ionicLoading.show({
          template: 'Loading Blogs...'
        });
    $scope.blogs = [];
    $scope.$on("TMSApp.blogs",function(_, result){
        result.posts.forEach(function(b){
            $scope.blogs.push({
                name:b.author.name,
                title:$sce.trustAsHtml(b.title),
                avatar:b.author.avatar_URL
            });
        });
        $ionicLoading.hide();
    });
    TMSSvc.loadBlogs();
}

function TMSSvc($http,$rootScope){
    this.loadBlogs= function(){
        $http.get("http://localhost/IonicDemo/webService/getBlogs.php")
          .success(function(result){
              $rootScope.$broadcast("TMSApp.blogs",result);
          });
    }
}
```

and PHP web service

```
<?php

require_once("conn.php");

class getBlogs{

    function __construct($db){
        $this->mysqli = $db->getLink();

    }

    function getAllBlogs(){
        header("HTTP/1.1 400 VALID REQUEST");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
        header("content-type:application/json");
        $qry = "SELECT * FROM services";
        $res = $this->mysqli->query($qry);
        if(!$res){
          echo $this->mysqli->error;
        }
        $data = array();
        while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
            $data = $row;
            echo json_encode($data);
        }
        //$data;
        //echo $data;
    }
}

$gb = new getBlogs($db);
$gb->getAllBlogs();

?>
```

Comment: This might be helpful to you
http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you have missed this line in your backend. I am not a php programmer but This is how I have done it in my node app.

`"Access-Control-Allow-Origin", 'http://localhost:8100'`

and in my frontEnd

```
myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) {

    // CORS

    $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];

    // Ionic uses AngularUI Router which uses the concept of states
    // Learn more here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
    // Set up the various states which the app can be in.
    // Each state's controller can be found in controllers.js
    $stateProvider

    .state('initial', {
        url: "/initial",
        templateUrl: 'templates/initial.html',
        controller: 'initialController'

    });
});
```

Comment: what do you mean by in node app?

Comment: For backend I use NodeJS. you use php